# Compiling libptrace

Tags: compilation, libtool

Trying to compile libptrace (http://sourceforge.net/projects/libptrace/).  The project has not advertised any preferred means of requesting support (*Unfortunately, this project hasn't indicated the best way to get help*).  Anywho, the problem I'm running into is as follows:

```
% ./build.sh
% ...[SUCCESS]
% ./configure
% ...[SUCCESS]
% make
Making all in src
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/xxx/build/libptrace-git.git/src'
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `../lib/libgnu.la', needed by `libptrace.la'.  Stop.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/xxx/build/libptrace-git.git/src'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/xxx/build/libptrace-git.git'
make: *** [all] Error 2
%
```

If you google libptrace and libgnu.la, you get zero hits.  Grepping for it in the source take fresh out of git, you get:

```
% grep -sre libgnu.la *
src/Makefile.in:libptrace_la_DEPENDENCIES = ../lib/libgnu.la
src/Makefile.in:libptrace_la_LIBADD = ../lib/libgnu.la
src/Makefile.am:libptrace_la_LIBADD = ../lib/libgnu.la
src/Makefile:libptrace_la_DEPENDENCIES = ../lib/libgnu.la
src/Makefile:libptrace_la_LIBADD = ../lib/libgnu.la
```

I have no idea how to generate a libtool archive file, and source doesn't seem to have any make targets or scripts otherwise to do so.

An note on admin: please add the tag `libptrace' to this question - obviously a very popular topic - I can't do so as I don't meet the 1.5K point count :(

---

In response to Mel's amendment to build.sh, Here are the new errors generated on `make':

```
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../.. -I../../src    -g -O2 -Wall -MT test-linux-dlsym.o -MD -MP -MF                     .deps/test-linux-dlsym.Tpo -c -o test-linux-dlsym.o test-linux-dlsym.c
mv -f .deps/test-linux-dlsym.Tpo .deps/test-linux-dlsym.Po
/bin/sh ../../libtool --tag=CC   --mode=link gcc  -g -O2 -Wall   -o test-linux-dlsym test-linux-dlsym.o            ../../src/libptrace.la 
libtool: link: gcc -g -O2 -Wall -o .libs/test-linux-dlsym test-linux-dlsym.o  ../../src/.libs/libptrace.so         -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/usr/local/lib
test-linux-dlsym.o: In function `main':
/home/XXX/dev/insecurity/build/libptrace-git/tests/linux/test-linux-dlsym.c:24: undefined reference to             `ptrace_elf_get_link_map_head'
/home/XXX/dev/insecurity/build/libptrace-git/tests/linux/test-linux-dlsym.c:40: undefined reference to             `ptrace_elf_get_link_map_next'
/home/XXX/dev/insecurity/build/libptrace-git/tests/linux/test-linux-dlsym.c:31: undefined reference to             `ptrace_elf_get_symtab'
/home/XXX/dev/insecurity/build/libptrace-git/tests/linux/test-linux-dlsym.c:32: undefined reference to             `ptrace_elf_get_strtab'
/home/XXX/dev/insecurity/build/libptrace-git/tests/linux/test-linux-dlsym.c:33: undefined reference to             `ptrace_elf_get_hash'
/home/XXX/dev/insecurity/build/libptrace-git/tests/linux/test-linux-dlsym.c:34: undefined reference to             `ptrace_elf_get_hash_chains'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [test-linux-dlsym] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/XXX/dev/insecurity/build/libptrace-git.git/tests/linux'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/XXX/dev/insecurity/build/libptrace-git.git'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: As far as I can see Ronald Huizer is the only major developer of the library. In the logs are two email addresses: <ronald@comned.com> and <scrippie@xs4all.nl>. Have you tried to ask him directly?

Answer (score 0):

This is gnulib: http://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/

It can be install in Debian with `apt-get install gnulib`

Answer (score 0):

builds on Ubuntu 10.10, gnulib is required as noted above and probably a whole bunch of build tools (autoconf, automake)

below patch fixes a link error which occurs when building git cc97c9e3d830bd1d567011ec099846343cef547a

diff --git a/src/Makefile.am b/src/Makefile.am
index 6de8cf2..5f8d9bc 100644
--- a/src/Makefile.am
+++ b/src/Makefile.am
@@ -23,8 +23,8 @@ endif
 if TARGET_LINUX
 libptrace_la_SOURCES += libptrace_linux.c libptrace_linux.h            \
                         libptrace_wrapper.c libptrace_wrapper.h                \
-                       libptrace_linux_procfs.c libptrace_linux_procfs.h
-#                        libptrace_elf.c libptrace_elf.h
+                       libptrace_linux_procfs.c libptrace_linux_procfs.h \
+                       libptrace_elf.c libptrace_elf.h
 libptrace_la_HEADERS += libptrace_linux.h libptrace_wrapper.h
 if TARGET_I386
 libptrace_la_SOURCES += libptrace_linux_x86.c libptrace_linux_x86.h
@@ -38,8 +38,8 @@ endif

if TARGET_FREEBSD
 libptrace_la_SOURCES += libptrace_freebsd.c libptrace_freebsd.h                \
-                        libptrace_wrapper.c libptrace_wrapper.h
-#                        libptrace_elf.c libptrace_elf.h
+                        libptrace_wrapper.c libptrace_wrapper.h                \
+                       libptrace_elf.c libptrace_elf.h
 libptrace_la_HEADERS += libptrace_freebsd.h libptrace_wrapper.h
 if TARGET_I386
 libptrace_la_SOURCES += libptrace_freebsd_x86.c libptrace_freebsd_x86.h

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this only works on linux. If you want this to work on other systems, you will need to write a src/libptrace_config.h header in configure.ac as can be seen by `grep COMPILE_HDR configure.ac`.

Secondly, the following patch is all I need to get the point where the generated header is missing on my system. Of course gnulib needs to be installed and gnulib-tool must be in $PATH.

```
diff --git a/build.sh b/build.sh
index 81caf8a..cc195c4 100755
--- a/build.sh
+++ b/build.sh
@@ -1,7 +1,7 @@
 #!/bin/sh

 # Import gnulib modules which we use
-gnulib-tool --import stdint
+gnulib-tool --libtool --import stdint

 # Update timestamp to make sure autoconf rebuilds everything.
 touch configure.ac
```

Comment: Hi Mel, this has helped move things along, but hasn't fixed the problem.  I have add `--libtool' to build.sh, and started the process from a fresh git checkout.  gnulib-tool is the latest and in $PATH.  I now get a new set of errors.  Also, the target arch is a 64-bit Linux system, just to narrow that down.  I'll post the new errors back into the question section above.